# docker with AWS: Which directory inside the docker container is the AWS credentials looked for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am building app with docker and I am using `boto3` sdk for AWS. I have set the credentials with docker but I am getting "botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials". I would like to know the directory it is searching for these credentials so I could put the `.aws` folder there.

Comment: It depends on the user that your docker is running under, as specified in your dockerfile. If root, then under `/root/.aws` should work

Comment: You can pass the credentials as environment variable to docker and use it

Comment: ...or the EC2 metadata service, or a JWT-based path on EKS.  The important detail is that all of the file- or environment-based paths need to be in the container's isolated environment, so you may need a `docker run -v` option to mount a host directory into the container.